# Achievement progress with Restart at Checkpoint

Tags: achievements, bioshock-infinite

I am currently playing through the game a second time on 1999 mode.  On this playthrough I am aiming to get the Eavesdropper and Sightseer achievements.  Because being revived costs so much money, I have taken to restarting from the last checkpoint upon death.  What I am wondering is if the checkpoint is from before the time when I got a voxophone, if I need to get it another time.

My observations so far:

- The achievement progress meter only shows the first time in a play session when you pick up the voxophone.
- If you shut down the game/console and then continue, the achievement progress meter will appear again, for the same voxophone.

Running around and getting the same few items every time I die in a difficult fight is getting a bit old and I wonder if someone can confirm the exact way the achievements are accumulated.

Comment: `If you shut down the game/console and then continue, the achievement progress meter will appear again, for the same voxophone.` That's because the game only saves at checkpoints, **not** when you quit the game. So as long as you restart a checkpoint, the game knows what you've done; but once you shut it down, it won't remember (since it didn't save)

Comment: Yes, i knew that, but since the progress meter didn't show up when simply restarting from the previous checkpoint, some meta data is being saved.  I was just hoping someone had difinitive answers on what was saved when.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the game, for it to record the progress of the Voxophone. For example if you pick up Voxophone XYZ and shut off the game, return to main menu, or restart from check point "before" it autosaves, then the progress is lost and the Voxophone has to be obtained again.

I have confirmed this 100%. Once you unlock a Voxophone, you have to reach the next "autosave" location, for it to save it as an unlockable into memory.